# DocuSign RESTAPI Consent Status

Tags: docusignapi

How to know whether a user has consented for API Integration? I have read through the entire REST API documentation and ran through the SDK but don't see any specifics.

In UserSetting we have two additional options "canSendAPIRequests" and "apiAccountWideAccess", but don't see any specific information.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that from the API, because it's a bit of a catch22, in order to call an API you need user to consent for your app to make API calls, which means that you won't be able to ever get a negative answer. You can check this in the UI, but I guess that's not what you wanted to do here.